# Value of an integer variable in one view always showing 0(ZERO) in another view

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to access tag value of a button of a view to another view but it always shows zero.

I declare an integer variable: NSInteger tag; in interface part of songView.h and set its @property(nonatomic) NSInteger tag;
In songView.m synthesize it as @synthesize tag;
Now I assign it the tag value of button like this:

```
-(IBAction)track1ButtonPressed:(id) sender
{
 self.tag = [sender tag];
}
```

Now I want to access this(tag) value in another view i.e. audioView, I code like this in audioView.m:

```
songView *songview=[songView alloc];
if (songview.tag==1)
{}
else{}
```

By running this code always else part execute because the value of songview.tag is 0(ZERO),
I also set the tag value of button as 1 in IB.

Comment: `[songView alloc];` - but where is init? And why for heaven sake `songview.tag` should be equal 1 the next string it's been initialized?

Comment: becoz tag is the tag attribute of a button in songview whose value I have set 1 in IB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to declare integer variable with different name other than tag..ex: NSInteger btnTag;
Because in general for any view the tag is zero

Comment: That is correct but you can redefine @property in a subclass, as long as you are extending its scope. So this should be fine, although unnecessary.

Comment: Still its showing 0(zero), in its own view its value is 0. Means -(IBAction)track1ButtonPressed:(id) sender { self.tag = [sender tag]; } self.tag value is 0.

Comment: check your button tag once again.Try to print it in debugger console

Comment: I have tried it. Now its printing the right value in its own view means value of self.bttag is correct, but in second view i.e. in songView *songview=[songView alloc];
if (songview.bttag==1)
{}
else{} its printing the value of "songview.tag" again 0(zero).

Comment: I think in songView you are  assigning btn tag in viewdidload function right?
Do these things in '- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil' function..

& SongView *sv=[[SongView alloc]init];
NSLog (@"%i",sv.btn.tag);

Try this

Comment: @kishorebjv: Actually, my aim is to play different song according to which button pressed. For this in I have display the list of songs in the form of buttons in "songView", Now when any button will pressed, respective song should be play in another i.e. "vedioView". As the vedioView will appear it should check that which button is pressed in "songView" on the basis of button's tag and should play the respective song. I have apply the conditions on button tag in viewWillAppear function like this: -

Comment: (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{songView *songview=[[songView alloc] initWithNibName:nil  bundle:nil];
if (songview.bttag==1) {
NSString *urlStr = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Abhilasha - Wadiyan Mera Daman.mp3" ofType:nil];
NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:urlStr];
audioPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
[self.view addSubview:audioPlayer.view];
audioPlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,50, 780, 100);  
[audioPlayer play];
}

Comment: --in continuation--  else {NSString *urlStr = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"barebear.wav" ofType:nil];NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:urlStr];audioPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];[self.view addSubview:audioPlayer.view];audioPlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,50, 780, 100);[audioPlayer play];}  Here the value of songview.bttag always 0 so always else part executes.

Comment: in songsViewController create a IBAction function for button ,
When he tappes on that button, load videoViewController,

In videoViewController ,according to the button tag play the song

I think you are new to Xcode like me..;)

Comment: @ kishorebjv: dear exactly the same thing I m doing.. but problem is that in videoViewController button tag automatically becomes 0.In songsViewController its value is correct as I use this value in videoViewController it becomes 0. You r absolutely right I m new to Xcode :)

Comment: its not only button tag,check with sample integer variable..it 'll show zero only..I can help you if you are able to show the sample code..!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to not only to allocate your objects, but also initialize it. So replace

```
songView *songview=[songView alloc];
```

with

```
CGRect songFrame = CGRectMake(0.f, 0.f, 120.f, 120.f);
songView *songview=[[songView alloc] initWithFrame:songFrame];
```

`initWithFrame` is the designated initializer for a `UIView` and I suppose your songView class is a subclass of `UIView`.

Then I am not sure if `assign` is the default modifier for `@property`, to make sure define your tag property as

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) NSInteger tag;
```

Then it should work. If not, set a breakpoint into your `track1ButtonPressed:(id) sender` method to see it is getting called and inspect the `sender` object manually using the debugger.

Comment: Still it showing 0(zero), in its own view its value is 0. Means -(IBAction)track1ButtonPressed:(id) sender
{
 self.tag = [sender tag];
} self.tag value is 0.

Comment: and what about the sender? is it the right object? try entering `po sender` into the gdb console and check if it is the right view.

Comment: I don't know how to enter po sender into the gdb console and check if it is the right view. Actually I am very new in iPhone so Please guide me.

Comment: Set a breakpoint as described in my answer. When the program stops at the breakpoint, open the Console, which can be found in the run menu and type `po sender` `po` stands for print object and calls the description method on the specified object. If it returns 0 then the sender is nil.